# Git, rebasing an incorrectly branched branch

Tags: git

```
git clone blah
git checkout -b development
git checkout -b bug581
hack hack
git checkout -b bug588
hack hack
```

oh wait, bug 588 should sprout from development, not 581.

```
git rebase --onto development bug581 bug588
```

gives me:

```
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

err, but i dont? git status shows working directory is clean. so lets stash just for giggles.

```
git stash
git rebase --onto development bug581 bug588
```

ok now it works, but its pulling the history of bug 581 and 588, i just want the history of 588, not what was in 581.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673952/fixing-published-branch-with-wrong-parent-branch

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm on a mac, and this obscure config change seemed to fix all my woes regarding unstaged changes when there were none.

```
git config --global core.trustctime false
```

I think it's to do with differences between windows file times, linux file times and mac file times. who knows, feel free to comment if you do.

Comment: Same problem on OSX Snow Leopard following a bunch of renames, working on a NFS mount.  Config change worked --Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you have auto rebase turned on?

look in your ~/.gitconfig or .git/config for

```
[branch "master"]
  rebase = true
```

or

```
[branch]
  autosetuprebase = always
```

Answer (score 0):

The second time you do "hack hack", is where your unstaged changes occurred.

Comment: well i thought it was fairly obvious from my language that any changes were committed so the working directory would be clean.

Comment: @devians: You never once mention a commit.  We are programmers, be precise.

Comment: "git status shows working directory is clean" would imply so. In fact, considering the problem is elsewhere i think its fair to assume that i'm always committed with a clean working directory.

Comment: @devians: Hmm, could you confirm that the file line endings are as expected? I've had weird things like that on windows with specific crlf settings?  What platform are you on, anyway?