# Intermittent git error: "Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes."

Tags: git, rebase

I see a lot of intermittent git errors when changing to or rebasing branches. Sometimes it will tell me I can't change branches because it would conflict with unstaged changes, even though my branch is clean (`git status` shows "nothing to commit, working directory clean"). If I try the same command again, it works the second time. Similarly, I have a command to rebase all of my branches:

```
'for i in $(git br | grep -e "\srf-"); do git co $i; git rebase master || break; done; git co master'
```

A lot of times it will break in the middle saying:

```
Cannot rebase: You have unstaged changes.
Please commit or stash them.
```

When I run `git status`, again, "nothing to commit, yada yada". If I just run the command again, it works, or ends up breaking on a different branch instead. Running it a handful of times it will eventually get through all of them without any intervention from me. Why do I keep getting these kinds of error messages when I have no unstaged changes anywhere? It seems like maybe git hasn't finished whatever operation it was handling before, so if it's something like that I'm wondering if there's a way to explicitly wait for it to be done.

I found a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358872/git-cannot-rebase-because-of-uncommitted-changes) of [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167542/weird-git-rebase-error) similar questions, but it looks like for other people it's consistent and for me it's not. The command ends up going through if I try it again.

git version: 1.9.1

OS: Linux Mint, kernel: 3.16.0-38-generic

Comment: I assume `co` is checkout and `br` is branch?

Comment: Could you try adding a `sleep 2` at the beginning or at the end of the loop?

Comment: Is there a way to clone your repo? It is difficult for me to recreate the environment...

Comment: Is your branch connected with an upstream branch ? If not, try doing that and see if things improve.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII, yes, sorry, those are aliases for `checkout` and `branch` respectively.

Comment: @RiccardoPetraglia, sorry it's a private repo that I'm working on right now. I tried tossing in a `sleep 0.1` and the issue seems to happen less often, though it still shows up some.

Comment: @AnkitBhatnagar I'm not sure I understand. This is just happening between branches locally.

Comment: after checkout/creating a local branch, you need to do "git push -u origin <branch>", then it connects to upstream. That's what I meant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This seems to be caused by the fact that the git repo is stored in a Dropbox folder. When I pause syncing on Dropbox, everything seems to rebase cleanly without hiccups.