# Cannot continue git rebase

Tags: git

Here's what I have tried. Hopefully somebody has a moment to look at this and suggest something. Thanks!

Edit: I believe I have answered my own question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12760672/906794

- Clone my repo

  ```
  $ git clone leoj3n/roots
  Cloning into 'roots'...
  remote: Counting objects: 3177, done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1362/1362), done.
  remote: Total 3177 (delta 2117), reused 2761 (delta 1792)
  Receiving objects: 100% (3177/3177), 1.40 MiB | 609 KiB/s, done.
  Resolving deltas: 100% (2117/2117), done.
  Checking out files: 100% (146/146), done.
  ```
- Change directory

  ```
  $ cd roots
  ```
- Check status

  ```
  roots(parent) $ git status
  # On branch parent
  nothing to commit (working directory clean)
  ```
- Add upstream

  ```
  roots(parent) $ git remote add upstream retlehs
  roots(parent) $ git remote
  origin
  upstream
  ```
- Fetch

  ```
  roots(parent) $ git fetch --all
  Fetching origin
  Fetching upstream
  remote: Counting objects: 70, done.
  remote: Compressing objects: 100% (30/30), done.
  remote: Total 56 (delta 28), reused 51 (delta 23)
  Unpacking objects: 100% (56/56), done.
  From git://github.com/retlehs/roots
   * [new branch]      classic    -> upstream/classic
   * [new branch]      grunt      -> upstream/grunt
   * [new branch]      improve_sidebar_config -> upstream/improve_sidebar_config
   * [new branch]      master     -> upstream/master
   * [new branch]      vcard_refactor -> upstream/vcard_refactor
   * [new tag]         5.1.0      -> 5.1.0
   * [new tag]         5.2.0      -> 5.2.0
   * [new tag]         6.0.0      -> 6.0.0
   * [new tag]         6.1.0      -> 6.1.0
  ```
- Rebase `parent` onto `upstream/master`

  ```
  roots(parent) $ git rebase -i upstream/master

  <<<<<< BEGIN WHAT I HAD IN vi >>>>>>
  pick 4904103 improved url cleaning for child themes
  s 986e6de added some is_child_theme() checks
  s 2860aee urls now look like /child/css/*
  s 4282ee0 Look for files in child, then in roots
  p bf9a89a Now using Theme Hook Alliance
  f 56d1211 Added THA utility script
  f 7702269 Added missing hooks
  f 14204d8 Support for multisite
  f aca4577 No more multisite rewrites
  f 8144b83 Revert some changes
  pick fbf1dec Added filter to disable sidebars
  pick 9b77e72 Added font-awesome
  f 161864d Remove test code
  <<<<<< END WHAT I HAD IN vi >>>>>>
  ```

  Then I get this error:

  ```
  error: could not apply 4904103... improved url cleaning for child themes

  When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
  If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
  To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
  Could not apply 4904103... improved url cleaning for child themes
  ```
- Resolve the conflicts

  ```
  roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ git mergetool
  merge tool candidates: opendiff kdiff3 tkdiff xxdiff meld tortoisemerge gvimdiff diffuse ecmerge p4merge araxis bc3 emerge vimdiff
  Merging:
  lib/config.php

  Normal merge conflict for 'lib/config.php':
    {local}: modified file
    {remote}: modified file
  Hit return to start merge resolution tool (opendiff): 
  2012-10-06 05:10:11.363 FileMerge[22088:707] Unable to load platform at path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
  2012-10-06 05:10:11.364 FileMerge[22088:707] Unable to load platform at path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform
  ```

  Note I get some errors running Opendiff.
- Done resolving conflicts, so continue

  ```
  roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ git rebase --continue
  You must edit all merge conflicts and then
  mark them as resolved using git add
  ```
- Huh? Check status:

  ```
  roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ git status
  # Not currently on any branch.
  # You are currently rebasing.
  #   (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
  #
  # Changes to be committed:
  #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  #
  #   modified:   lib/config.php
  #   modified:   lib/htaccess.php
  #
  # Untracked files:
  #   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
  #
  #   lib/config.php.orig
  ```
- Remove merge backup file

  ```
  roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ rm lib/config.php.orig 

  roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ git status
  # Not currently on any branch.
  # You are currently rebasing.
  #   (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
  #
  # Changes to be committed:
  #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  #
  #   modified:   lib/config.php
  #   modified:   lib/htaccess.php
  #
  ```
- Continue rebase

  ```
  roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ git rebase --continue
  You must edit all merge conflicts and then
  mark them as resolved using git add
  ```
- Hmm, try adding everything

  ```
  roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ git add -A

  roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ git rebase --continue
  You must edit all merge conflicts and then
  mark them as resolved using git add
  ```

This is when I gave up and made this S.O. question.

---

Here's some more info:

```
roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ git diff-files --ignore-submodules
:100644 100644 f65cf1dc4573c51e54d7cf3772d06caf96726616 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js
```

I think it may have to do with the mergetool opendiff—notice the errors above.

```
roots(parent|REBASE-i) $ git config --list
user.name=xxxxxx
user.email=xxxxxx
credential.helper=osxkeychain
alias.pu=!git fetch origin -v; git fetch upstream -v; git merge upstream/master
alias.co=checkout
alias.ci=commit
alias.rb=rebase
color.ui=auto
core.excludesfile=/Users/xxxxxx/.gitignore_global
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
core.ignorecase=true
core.precomposeunicode=false
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=git@github.com:leoj3n/roots.git
branch.parent.remote=origin
branch.parent.merge=refs/heads/parent
remote.upstream.url=git://github.com/retlehs/roots.git
remote.upstream.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Surprisingly, I was able to rebase on my windows machine using tortoisemerge.

Comment: From the status message that you get, I assume you must be running at least git 1.7.12, in which case the "You must edit all merge conflicts and then [..]" error is output when `git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules` exits with a non-zero exit code.  Could you just run `git diff-files --ignore-submodules` and paste the output into your question?

Comment: See the edit at the end.

Comment: Very strange - I'm not sure why `assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js` is appearing in the `git diff-files` output, but not `git status`.  Is that file present in the working tree at the moment?

Comment: Yes it is. I think it may have something to do with the errors

```2012-10-06 05:10:11.363 FileMerge[22088:707] Unable to load platform at path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform
2012-10-06 05:10:11.364 FileMerge[22088:707] Unable to load platform at path /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform```

when using mergetool opendiff...

Comment: I suspect that they aren't relevant, in fact.  If all you want to do is get past this, I suspect it will work if you do: `git add assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js` and then `git rebase --continue`.  However, this does look like very odd behaviour, which might be worth reporting to the git mailing list.

Comment: Is it possible that you have some surprising config options set?  If you include the output of `git config --list` (having removed any personal or sensitive information from that) it might be helpful.

Comment: I was able to rebase on my windows machine using tortoisemerge...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the problem was because of file times being off. This repo is on a network drive and is accessed/modified by both Windows and Macs...

All I needed to do, it seems, is change a single configuration item...

```
git config --global core.trustctime false
```

The solution was found at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255700/906794

Comment: Who could have thought. Glad you found your answer