# Git rebase merge conflict cannot continue

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm trying to rebase 'dev' to catch up to 'master' branch.

```
$ git checkout dev 
$ git rebase master 
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: Corrected compilation problems that came from conversion from SVN.
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       src/com/....
<stdin>:125: trailing whitespace.
/**
<stdin>:126: trailing whitespace.
 *
<stdin>:127: trailing whitespace.
 */
<stdin>:128: trailing whitespace.
package com....
<stdin>:129: trailing whitespace.

warning: squelched 117 whitespace errors
warning: 122 lines add whitespace errors.
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging src/com/....
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in src/com/...
Failed to merge in the changes.
Patch failed at 0001 Corrected compilation problems that came from conversion from SVN.

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".

$ vi src/com/.....   { fixed the merge issue on one file } 
$ git add -A . 
$ git rebase --continue 
src/com/....: needs merge
You must edit all merge conflicts and then
mark them as resolved using git add
$ vi src/com....      { verified, no >>> or <<< left, no merge markers } 
$ git rebase --continue 
Applying: Corrected compilation problems that came from conversion from SVN.
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem run "git rebase --continue".
If you would prefer to skip this patch, instead run "git rebase --skip".
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing run "git rebase --abort".
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: there are cases where a `git rebase --skip` could still not work properly. Until Git 2.0.2 (July 2014). See [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25107391/6309)

Comment: With problems like this, sometimes it's best to start the merge over and _be extra careful_ to do everything right (which is not easy).

Answer (score 312, accepted):

There are a couple situations where I've seen `rebase` get stuck. One is if the changes become null (a commit has changes that were already made previously in the rebase) in which case you may have to use `git rebase --skip`.

It's pretty easy to tell. If you do `git status` it should show no changes. If so just skip it. If that isn't the case please post a copy of `git status` and I can try to help further.

Comment: No that was it, there were "no" changes due.  I skipped it and compared the file afterwards it was what it should have been.

Comment: This helped me when my 'git pull --rebase origin master" appeared to get stuck in a loop between needing to resolve conflicts and skip. After a bit more patience, I am fixed, ty!

Comment: git status returns: " rebase in progress; onto <commitnumber> You are currently rebasing branch '<branchname>' on '<commitnumber>'. (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue") ".

git rebase --continue returns no changes whereas git rebase --skip do but in my case I'm getting that situation again and again. Is that right or there's something wrong?

Comment: Thanks. I was worried `--skip` would do worse than just move on with the changes I made.

Comment: In my case both Intellij Idea GUI and SourceTree were showing that each file was added into commit, whereas `git status` showed, that there was a file that was modified, but was not added into commit. Performing `add somefile.txt` allowed to continue with rebasing.

Comment: skipping is also the risk of loosing some changes. Git fools sometimes the user ...

Comment: I had the same situation and the reason was that both branches contained the same commit added by using cherry-pick

Answer (score 21):

One of the times that I have run into this issue is when doing a `git commit` after a `git add`. So, the following sequence will produce the rebase error you mention:

```
git add <file with conflict>
git commit -m "<some message>"  
git rebase --continue
```

While, the sequence below runs without any errors, and continues the rebase:

```
git add <file with conflict>
git rebase --continue
```

It might be possible that `git add -A` with the "All" option is creating a similar situation. (Please note, I am very inexperienced in git, so this answer may not be correct.) To be safe, the `git rebase --skip` seems to also work well in this situation.

Answer (score 6):

Note: Git 2.0.2 (July 2014) has fixed one case where a `git rebase --skip` would get stuck and wouldn't be able to go on with the current rebase.
See [commit 95104c7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/95104c7e257652b82aed089494def344e3938928) by [brian m. carlson (`bk2204`)](https://github.com/bk2204)

### `rebase--merge`: fix `--skip` with two conflicts in a row

> If `git rebase --merge` encountered a conflict, **`--skip` would not work if the next commit also conflicted**.
>   The `msgnum` file would never be updated with the new patch number, so no patch would actually be skipped, resulting in an inescapable loop.
>
> Update the `msgnum` file's value as the first thing in call_merge.
>   This also avoids an "`Already applied`" message when skipping a commit.
>   There is no visible change for the other contexts in which call_merge is invoked, as the
>   msgnum file's value remains unchanged in those situations.

Answer (score 6):

After a rebase with lots of conflicts (long `git status`) I couldn't figure out what it was that I was supposed to stage. I use Git integrated with PhpStorm and it didn't show any unstaged files.

`git add .` didn't solve it but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12759390/cannot-continue-git-rebase#comment17240698_12759390) recommended calling
`git diff-files --ignore-submodules`. That showed three files I had to specifically git add and that did the trick.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ vi src/com....      { verified, no >>> or <<< left, no merge markers } 
$ git rebase --continue
```

Looks like you forgot to `git add` your changes...

Comment: It was only a "verify" no changes were needed the 2nd time  ... git add was right above it.

Comment: Right, you used `git add` and then continued the merge, and it stopped because another file has conflicts, so you need to fix that one, as well.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's the same file that is reporting needs merging.  ok just for you I'll do another "git add", but it's the same result.

Comment: Thanks!  That was my situation: I resolved conflicts but not staged the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this when I had a file that was removed in both branches some number of commits in. I had to `git rm` the file to get rebase to continue.

I tried to reproduce this but failed to get "cannot continue". In case anyone wants to try their hand, here's my what I tried:

```bash
mkdir t
cd t
git init
echo a > a.txt && echo b > b.txt && git add . && git commit -m "+a +b"

git checkout -b no-a
echo b1 > b.txt && git add b.txt && git commit -m "~b1"
git rm a.txt && echo b2 > b.txt && echo c1 > c.txt && git add . && git commit -m "-a ~b +c"

git checkout main
git rm a.txt && echo b0 > b.txt && echo c0 > c.txt && git add . && git commit -m "~b +c"
git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all

git checkout no-a
git status
git rebase main
ls
cat b.txt
git status

git checkout no-a b.txt
git commit -m "-a ~b"
git rebase --skip

git checkout no-a c.txt && git checkout main a.txt
git commit -m "~b +c"
git rebase --skip
```