# How to keep branch hierarchy in Git?

Tags: git

Simplyfiing I have a created a git branch structure like this:

[image]

Generated from:

```
git init
echo "Hello World" > file1.txt
git add file1.txt
git commit -m "Hello world"
git checkout -b A
echo "This is from A branch" > file2.txt
git add file2.txt
git commit -m "from A branch"
git checkout -b B
echo "This is from B branch" >> file2.txt
git commit -a -m "from B branch"
```

Now I clone this structure and synchronize `master`, `A` and `B` branches:

```
git clone /path-to-source/
git checkout -b master remotes/origin/master
git checkout -b A remotes/origin/A
```

and the cloned repository reflects the source hierarchy:

[image]

Now I return to source folder and add something to master and rebase A and B:

```
cd /path-to-source/
git checkout master
echo "more files" > file3.txt
git add file3.txt
git commit -m "Improved master"
git checkout A
git rebase master
git checkout B
git rebase A
```

[image]

The problem comes when I return to the cloned repository and try to keep this structure. If I just `pull` the `master` branch, I get this:

[image]

I can go to every branch and update:

```
git checkout A
git pull
```

but I get branch trees like this:

[image]

The question is, how to keep a clean clone of the repository? It is, I want to obtain this (manipulated graphic) in the cloned repository:

[image]

**Bonus**: If possible, I would like to find a way to keep also commits in the `A` or `B` branches like this:

[image]

generated from these commands in the source repository:

```
git checkout A
echo "something" > other.txt
git add other.txt
git commit -m "Other A commit"
git checkout B
git rebase A
```

**NOTE 1**: If that helps, cloned repository NEVER commits
**NOTE 2**: You can assume that there is only 1 user commiting to source repository

Comment: Not 100% sure, but pull should work on non-checked-out branches if they're set up as tracking the remote branches (read the manpage of git branch or git checkout to find more about tracking branches)

Comment: May be, but I need to do it in already checked out branches (the branch hierarchy is important in my project)

Comment: As a general note: Never rebase commits once they have been published.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rebasing means changing the SHA1, so your branch A in the clone is no longer valid.

You can follow "[How do I recover/resynchronise after someone pushes a rebase or a reset to a published branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084868/how-do-i-recover-resynchronise-after-someone-pushes-a-rebase-or-a-reset-to-a-pub)" to restore the cloned branch A (inspired from the "[RECOVERING FROM UPSTREAM REBASE](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_recovering_from_upstream_rebase)" section).

But if:

- those rebases are a frequent occurrence,
- you don't have any new commit on the clone for branch A and branch B

You might want to simply reset those branches (on the clone) based on their `origin/A` and `origin/B`: you reset branch `A` HEAD to `origin/A`.

```
git branch -f origin/A
```

Comment: Why "if those rebases are a frequent occurrence"? Performing issues may be? Anyway commits in the A branch are rare, but occour and the idea is to automatize all this in a shell script. Reading your reference.. thanks

Comment: @Ivan no performance, just that the way to recover is a bit cumbersome, and useful only if you did some commits in the branch on the clone, that you need to replay on top of `origin/A` once you are fetching the new `A` history (because `A` was rebased in the upstream repo). But, if you didn't do anything on `A` in the clone, then the solution is straightforward: simply reset your `A` to `origin/A`.

Comment: @Ivan and considering your notes, the `git branch -f A origin/A` could be your very simple automation right there.

Comment: Perfect, it works. But just a question: why not `git checkout A` + `git rebase origin/A`?

Comment: @Ivan Because `A` (in the clone) contains the same commits than `origin/A` (except with different SHA1), and the rebase would simply ignore those identical commits when replaying `A` on top of `origin/A`. The end result would be the same as directly resetting `A` HEAD to `origin/A`.