# command to determine the upstream ref of the current HEAD?

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm looking for what I hope is the *simple one line command* to determine the the correct upstream ref for the currently checked out branch?

Essentially *something like*

`git branch --remote HEAD`

which (if it worked) would convert the symbolic pattern HEAD to the current branch name, and then the option `--remote` then changes it to the ref of the remote-tracking branch. (But it doesn't do that!)

If I have branch `morehelp` with a config of

```
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/morehelp
```

The simple command line would return `refs/remotes/origin/morehelp` which is it's upstream tracking branch (ideal for the `git reset --hard <ref>` case of an update by overwrite)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you want

```
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name @{u}
```

`@{u}` is the abbreviation for the upstream tracking branch of `HEAD` and the option tells `rev-parse` to print it in the format you want, rather than printing an SHA commit ID.

From `git help rev-parse`

```
   --symbolic
       Usually the object names are output in SHA1 form (with possible ^ prefix); this option makes them output in a form as close to the original
       input as possible.

   --symbolic-full-name
       This is similar to --symbolic, but it omits input that are not refs (i.e. branch or tag names; or more explicitly disambiguating
       "heads/master" form, when you want to name the "master" branch when there is an unfortunately named tag "master"), and show them as full
       refnames (e.g. "refs/heads/master").
```

Comment: that looks the business. I thought I'd been past that earlier but was trying `git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD` with some remote option which didn't work. It  feels like something that should be more obvious. (even the `@{u}` with it's comment "A missing ref defaults to the current branch.).

Comment: _"It feels like something that should be more obvious."_ but this is Git, all the really useful commands are very non-obvious ;)

Comment: +100(b;-) for that. I'd been thinking of adding a `--to-usptream` to `git reset --hard <ref>` for my reset to upstream case when I pass one of my private development branches between machines via my Github repo. Now I can create an alias using your one-liner.

Comment: In fact `git reset --hard @{upstream}` is the right command to drop one's local commits, and change to the last fetched commit of the branch's upstream repo. Ideal for transferring a personal rebase between machines (e.g. a windows <-> Linux transfer)