# git rebase upstream/master vs git pull --rebase upstream master

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

Is there a difference between `git rebase upstream/master` and `git pull --rebase upstream master`, and if so, what? The remote could be any remote, not necessarily upstream.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `git pull --rebase` will [fetch (`git fetch`)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) first, updating `upstream/master` commits.

If you just rebase *without* first updating `upstream/master`, you won't get the same result.

I illustrate it in "[`master` branch and '`origin/master`' have diverged, how to 'undiverge' branches'?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2452610/6309)"

---

[SnakE](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213376/) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602037/git-rebase-upstream-master-vs-git-pull-rebase-upstream-master/15602072?noredirect=1#comment46443846_15602072) that `git pull --rebase` isn't *exactly* `git fetch && git rebase origin/master`.
See "[what does "`git pull --rebase`" do?](http://gitolite.com/git-pull--rebase.html)"

```
(origin/master)
   |
A--B--C (master)
 \ 
  B'--D (actual origin/master after changing B and force pushing)
```

What `git pull --rebase` does, in this case, is:

```
git fetch origin
git rebase --onto origin/master B master
```

Here:

- origin/master is the new updated `origin/master` (`B'`)
- `B` is the old `origin/master` (before a fetch updated it)
- `master` is the branch to replay on top of `origin/master`

This differs from `git fetch` + `git rebase origin/master` in that the `pull --rebase` command tries to find out which commits are *really* your local ones, and which had come from upstream in an earlier fetch.

> To do this, it looks at the reflog of the remote tracking branch (`origin/master`, in this case). This reflog represents the tips of successive `git fetch` operations on `origin`, in "most recent first" order.
>
> For each reflog entry, (`origin/master@{1}`, then `...{2}`, and so on) it checks if that commit is an ancestor of the current branch head `master`. As soon as it finds one, it picks it as the starting point for the rebase (`B` in the example above).

Comment: So `git pull --rebase upstream master` is analogous to `git fetch upstream && git rebase upstream/master`?

Comment: Actually no. Imagine you pulled history `A-B` and made a change on top of it, `A-B-C`. Then somebody else amended `B` to `B'` and foce-pushed their changes so that the origin is now `A-B'-D`. Now if you do `git fetch && git rebase origin/master` the rebase will fail with conflicts. However `git pull --rebase` will figure it out and end up with `A-B'-D-C`. Some magic is definitely happening under the carpet in `pull --rebase`. Edit: [prooflink](http://gitolite.com/git-pull--rebase.html)

Comment: @SnakE good point, that you. I have included the `pull --rebase` algo in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: The magic is available directly in `git merge-base --fork-point`

Comment: @jthill since got 1.9.0+, I presume, since I documented fork-point there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20423029/6309

Comment: @VonC What is the use of the argument `B` in `git rebase --onto origin/master B master`? Git manual says it's `<upstream>`, but what would that mean when `--onto` option is specified?

Comment: @ibrahim5253 `B` is the first commit (included) you are rebasing on top of the branch referenced by `--onto`.