# Confused about git rebase

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

My workflow:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.abc.abc.com:abc/dev.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.abc.abc.com:abc/dev.git (push)
upstream  git@github.abc.abc.com:companyname/dev.git (fetch)
upstream  git@github.abc.abc.com:companyname/dev.git (push)
```

Fork git@github.abc.abc.com:companyname/dev.git using github web interface. Create git@github.abc.abc.com:abc/dev.git

Now:

```
1. git clone git@github.abc.abc.com:abc/dev.git
2. git remote add origin git@github.abc.abc.com:abc/dev.git
3. git remote add upstream git@github.abc.abc.com:companyname/dev.git 
4. git checkout -b upstream-master upstream/master
5. git checkout -b master origin/master
```

Now modify some code and create a commit on local master branch.

```
5.1. git add somecode.c
5.2. git commit -m "my commit for which I will make a PR" 
6. git push origin master
```

Now go to `git@github.abc.abc.com:abc/dev.git` on github web interface and create a PR for upstream/master:

Once the PR is merged, do:

```
7. git checkout upstream-master 
8. git pull --rebase
```

Now my local `upstream-master` has PR merge commit but `master` (which is origin/master) does not.

Q: Which branch should I rebase on which and why ?

After steps 7 and 8 should I do

`git rebase origin-master`

or should I do

```
git checkout origin-master 
git rebase upstream-master
```

Comment: I never see any place where you actually created a commit.  There is a lot of confusion here.

Comment: You might want to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602037/git-rebase-upstream-master-vs-git-pull-rebase-upstream-master

Comment: You may *ever so slightly* be conflating rebasing with pulling from another remote branch here.

Comment: @Bacon in addition to being crunchy and tasty, you are also spot on.  I think he is confused about merging vs. rebasing strategy.

Comment: Right. I think here's the OP would like to actually do a git rebase origin/master in his local upstream-master branch. I agree that a merge would be cleaner.

Comment: @Bacon exactly reverse. I wanted to get the PR merge commit which is available in upstream into my local origin/master.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What is not clear here? Please let me know.

Comment: This isn't really a rebase question, it's a question about pull strategy.

Comment: The unclear part is that you say doing a commit when you just indicate doing a push (which is a separate step in git, i.e you're pushing a local commit to the remote branch).

Comment: @Bacon I added 5.1 and 5.2 steps for creating a commit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is a question about pull strategy using `rebase`

Comment: I made some edits based on feedback in comments, is this clearer now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to retrieve in your local master something that was merged on the remote upstream/master branch, you should:

```
git checkout master
```

to position yourself into the local branch that you want to update

and then

```
git rebase upstream/master
```

To retrieve the modifications from the remove upstream/master branch into your current, local branch

Comment: That is the source of my confusion. Why should I not do : `git checkout upstream-master` and `git rebase master` . After all I am trying to `rebase` upstream-master onto master. No ?

Comment: Yes, so you need to position yourself into the branch where you want to retrieve the modifications, which is master, in this case. When rebasing, you specify the branch from which you want to get those modifications.