# How to move function declaration to another file yet retain Git history?

Tags: git, refactoring

I am refactoring a single-file PHP script to declare functions and classes in separate files. **How does one move a block of code from one file to another file yet preserve the Git history for each individual line?** I would like the ability to use at the very least `git blame` on the code. Comparing to older versions would also be helpful.

Note that I am not interested in 'workaround' solutions that would require additional commands or flags (such as `--follow`) on the code to view its 'old' history, for which the person viewing the history would have to know that the file needs special treatment. I am looking for a solution which writes the necessary metadata such that normal git commands such as `blame`, `log`, `diff`, and such 'just work' without presenting to them additional flags or arguments.

I have read quite a [few](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2011/01/refactoring-in-git.html) [posts](http://gitster.livejournal.com/35628.html) looking for solutions to [similar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845234/viewing-git-history-of-moved-files), but none that address the issue of `git blame` on individual lines. One solution that I think would work would be to [copy the file and its entire history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343266/copy-file-and-its-entire-history), then work off of that. However, that question remains without a satisfactory answer.

Comment: Note that `git blame` already tracks lines of code across files, but unless the files was renamed, you still have to pass additional options to tell Git to do the move/copy detection, perhaps because it's an expensive operation.

Comment: Suppose "Stas" writes a block of code and checks it into Git, and then I cut and paste the block into a different file. Now `git blame` will show that I've written that block of code. I am looking for a solution which will allow me to move the code, but it should still show that Stas wrote it, and when.

Comment: Have you read the [`git blame` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html) to see if it already does what you're looking for?

Comment: in particular, the `-C` thing is probably what you want (i've deleted my answer because while it's technically correct that git doesn't track this, in practice `-C` is probably good enough for what you need).

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of `--follow` and `-C1` but I'm really looking for a solution that 'rewrites' the history of the file to add the information for the original function author to the new location.

Comment: I find this to be very relevant. It could be expanded to a much broader question "How can I work on git as an **editor** and keep the original **author** as such?". Just like we can do with posts here on SEN. Answer is: we can't. But I wish we could.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Warning: This assumes that [rewriting history](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#problems-With-rewriting-history) is acceptable.  Do not use this unless you know the implications of rewriting history.**

To split a file into multiple files while maintaining history use [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'if [ -f original.php ]; then 
    echo part1.php part2.php part3.php | xargs -n 1 cp original.php; fi' HEAD
```

Then delete the lines that you do not want from each file (leaving only the desired functions and classes) and commit the result!

Comment: Note that the linked document is the git user manual, I didn't know about it until just now (I guess it has a low search ranking or something) but it's very detailed and seems like it will be really useful. I try to avoid "Thanks!" comments but I really would like to emphasize how important that link is. I bought a whole darn book in Git and that page still has some information that the book doesn't.