# Working with stable and development version of asmx service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx, git-extensions

I am developing asmx web service. It is consumed by ASP.Net website writing by some person. Both in development stage. If i edit web service, the web site loss authentication, if any errors it reflects.

Is there any best practice or configuration that push changes after i partially finish the web service and not affecting authentication. I am using git for version control. Any ideas?

Update: Git has any options to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17343266/copy-file-and-its-entire-history relevant

Answer (score 0):

Use a copy as development stage and make changes here. Once everything is tested, replace the "production" stage with your development copy.