# Merging from upstream repository with rewritten history

Tags: git, github

Upstream repository got its history rewritten and there is a number of forks which periodically merge changes from said repository.

I have noticed that the network graph on github looks very strange now, for each merge from upstream there appears to be two actual merges happening.

Do forkers need to do anything specific on their end to remedy this? Should the upstream maintainer do something (short of avoiding history rewrite in the future)?

Comment: Rewriting history on an upstream branch that is forked from it is generally considered a really bad practice. The only way I can think about circunventing it is stashing your, re-track upstream and apply the changes.

Comment: When upstream has force-pushed a rewritten history you should probably rebase your work on top of the new history. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084868/how-do-i-recover-resynchronise-after-someone-pushes-a-rebase-or-a-reset-to-a-pub) is a near duplicate.