# ci/cd independent microservices in monorepo with git bash

Tags: git, bash, continuous-integration, microservices, monorepo

Using Bash and git, how do I get a collection of directories containing files that differ from that last time the branch was merged into `master`?

Even better would be a collection of changed that match a pattern such as containing a particular file name , i.e. building a collection of changed directories containing `package.json` and a different collection of changed containing `requirements.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`git merge-base`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-base) to get the last merge:

```
git diff --name-only $(git merge-base --fork-point master myBranch)..myBranch
```

On the fork-point part, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20423029/6309).

From there, you can grep by pattern to filter out the result.

As torek adds in the comments, if fork-point is not needed, and using **[a pathspec](http://kgrz.io/git/2015/07/27/git-intro-to-pathspec.html)**

```
git diff --name-only master...myBranch -- requitements.txt
```

See "[What are the differences between double-dot "..." and triple-dot "`...`" in Git diff commit ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)"

[image: http://mythic-beasts.com/~mark/git-diff-help.png]

Comment: Note that if you don't need the `--fork-point` behavior, you can use the special semantics of triple-dot in `git diff`: `git diff --name-only master...myBranch`. (If your patterns are simple glob patterns you can do them in the `git diff` step as well, as pathspecs.)

Comment: @torek good point. I have included and illustrated it in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: fork-pont is needed in this case. Thank you both for the prefect answer to this question.