# How to remove github history for all team members

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project and using github as our source control server. The project is private and I want to make it public. But some credential is saved in the history of my git repo. I want to remove the history of commits and only keep the last commits for all branches. I know that I can do this by below commands.

```
Checkout

git checkout --orphan latest_branch
Add all the files

git add -A
Commit the changes

git commit -am "commit message"
Delete the branch

git branch -D master
Rename the current branch to master

git branch -m master
Finally, force update your repository

git push -f origin master
```

but I am worried about other team members. If I follow above steps to clear the history but other team members don't, will they have trouble when they run `git pull`? Or will they bring the history back when they run `git push`?

Comment: they should do what described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4084868/2303202)

Answer (score 0):

- Clone repository in state you want your project to go public
- Create new repository
- Push to that fresh repository

Repo will be fresh with no history as a good working base.

Comment: I am sure it works. But I don't want to rename our repo and I want to keep the current repo name. The reason is that we have a large team and I don't want to impact all other developers.

Comment: Git is about keeping history, so unless you push only part of it to different repo, you are out of luck i think, but i may be wrong

Comment: @ZhaoYi you can keep the two repo in different path in server

Comment: @ShiheZhang If I keep two repos in a different path, then another developer is still using the old path. He will bring all history back to the repo.

Comment: so you don't want the old repo?then just merge it into new one.

Comment: new repo on old path - no other way