# Git branch is a large number of commits ahead of master

Tags: git, branch

I have created a separate branch from master on a git repository. During that time, I made a few dozen commits on my branch, and something like a hundred commits were made to master. Now I want to merge my branch back into master. After first merging master into my branch, git says my branch is 2200 commits ahead of master, which must be wrong somehow. There are about 3000 commits in total in the repository.

What could cause something like this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be sure without access to the actual commits and repositories, but this is the sort of thing that happens if your upstream—the people in control of the repository from which you `git clone`d your own repository—have done a massive history rewrite.

The heart of the issue here is that "ahead" and "behind" don't mean what people want to think they mean at first, because people like to think of history as linear: thing X happened, then thing Y happened later, then thing Z.  History in Git is *not* linear: thing X happened while thing Y was also happening.  Thing Z tied X and Y together:

```
...--X--Y--Z   <-- present-day
```

is wrong and:

```
...--X
      \
       Z   <-- present-day
      /
...--Y
```

is right.  Neither X nor Y are "ahead of" or "behind" each other, even though both are quite clearly "behind" Z.

(Don't take this particular analogy too far: it's just meant as an illustration.  Starting from Z and working backwards, Git might show you Y first, then X, when Git shows you one commit at a time—but that doesn't mean there's some strong ordering between X and Y.  You might see Z then X then Y instead, just as easily.)

---

With the above in mind, suppose that you clone a repository that has some string of commits in it:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

Because your clone copies the actual commits, you get exactly-identical commits in your own (separate) repository:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
```

The `origin/master` is your Git's memory of their Git's `master`: their Git's `master` pointed to commit `H`.

You now make your own commits, in your own repository, on your own branch you call `feature`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master, origin/master
            \
             I--J   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Meanwhile, for some reason, the people in control of the repository you cloned decide they hate commits `G` and `H` and they replace them with improved commits `G'` and `H'`.  You now run `git fetch origin` to update *your* repository with *their* new commits, giving you this:

```
       G'-H'  <-- origin/master
      /
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- feature
```

Your branch is now *four* commits "ahead of" `origin/master`, and also two commits "behind" `origin/master`.  The four that you are ahead of them are `G`, `H`, `I`, and `J`—which as far as your Git is concerned, you must have written yourself, because `origin/master` goes from `H'` back to `G'` back to `F`, skipping over `G` and `H`.

(The two that you are "behind" are of course `G'` and `H'`.)

In this particular example you wind up just two extra ahead.  If they did a massive copy-and-substitute operation, using `git filter-branch` or the BFG or some such, though, you'll be hundreds or thousands of commits "ahead" of the ones they threw away, which your Git now thinks are your own work.  You fix this by, as Git puts it, ["recovering from an upstream rebase"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4084868/1256452).

Comment: I know there hasn't been a history rewrite, but thank you for the answer.

Comment: If that's not it, well, we'd need to see the actual repositories and what really did happen.