# Resolving conflicts when rebasing an old branch onto a branch migrated to Git LFS

Tags: git, git-lfs

I have a repository ("repo") that needs to be gradually migrated to a new repository ("repo-lfs"). repo-lfs uses LFS to store large files, while repo did not.

The intermediate state looks as follows:

```
repo-lfs: ---------------> main

repo:     ---------------> main
              \_________ release-1.0
```

Now I want to migrate the "release-1.0" branch to repo-lfs, which requires rebasing repo:release-1.0 onto repo-lfs:main. I have already added repo as a remote on repo-lfs, but a naïve rebase produces conflicts for every change to every file that was migrated to Git LFS:

```
$ git rebase --onto <correct commit on main> repo/main repo/release-1.0
Auto-merging xy.zip
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in xy.zip
[...]
Could not apply 96639f9... Edited xy.zip
Encountered 1 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't:
        xy.zip
```

How do I automatically resolve these "conflicts" in the obvious manner, i.e. by applying the change to the file in git LFS?

Comment: Did you try the strategy "ours" or "theirs" like `git rebase -s recursive -X ours --onto <correct commit on main> repo/main repo/release-1.0` ?

Comment: If repo/release-1.0 is made from an intermediate commit from repo/main, the rebase would need to be `git rebase --onto main $(git merge-base repo/main repo/release-1.0) repo/release-1.0`

Comment: @Reynadan Using the "ours" strategy will throw away all changes made to LFS-migrated files in the release-1.0 branch. What I want to achieve instead is that the changes are applied to the corresponding files in LFS.

Comment: @VonC I think you misunderstood what I was trying to achieve. The migrated repository should eventually mirror the original state. With your version, I would rebase the release branch on the latest commit on main, while I actually want it to start at the (equivalent of) the same commit it originally started from.

Comment: @mb-lang Got it, but the last two params seem fishy: In your question "`git rebase --onto <correct commit on main> repo/main repo/release-1.0`". A `rebase --onto B X Y` means "rebase all commits from *after* `X` up to `Y` onto `B`". In your case, you rebase onto `<the right commit on main>`, which is correct, as you explained. But I struggle to see on your graph "all commits *after* `repo/main` (?), up to "`repo/release-1.0`". Hence, my `$(git merge-base)` proposal. To start from the right commit to migrate the `repo/release-1.0` branch.

Comment: @VonC Ah, now I see what you were getting at. I just did a quick test: `git rebase --onto <ID> branch1 branch2` and `git rebase --onto <ID> $(git merge-base branch1 branch2) branch2` seem to be doing the same thing on my test repository. Not sure if this is an accident or intended, as I cannot find any description of this behavior in the git-rebase documentation.

Comment: OK, there's at least a little hint in the documentation of `git rebase`: The description of the `--fork-point` option mentions that it affects `git merge-base`, so even though the documentation does not state it explicitly, I think the implicit call to merge-base is intended and both versions of the command are correct.

Comment: @mb-lang I have written on fork-point before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20423029/6309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer my own question now:

You do not need to use `git rebase` and resolve the resulting conflicts at all. `git lfs migrate import` is completely deterministic, which allows you to avoid the problem altogether.

As long as you do not rewrite the history of `repo`, you can migrate new branches to `repo-lfs` by simply checking them out as a local branch in `repo-lfs` and running the exact same `git lfs migrate import` command that was originally used to migrate the `main` branch. Git LFS will produce the exact same commit hashes it previously produced for all commits shared between the release branch and `main`, which means the new branch will automatically be attached to the correct parent commit and the resulting history will match the history from the non-LFS repository perfectly.